# Static blocks in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: static-block

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 with Metroshop theme (from Themeforest).

I hope someone can help me or give any advice what I should to check.

In CMS/Static blocks I added new one (like in manual):

in example:

```
name: bottom4_promotional_static_block
id: bottom4_promotional_static_block
status: enabled
```

Then I pasted code (like in manual):
"

```
<div class="static-R-4">
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-1.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-2.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-3.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner last"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-4.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="static-R-4">
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-1.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-2.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-3.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
<div class="sampleBanner last"><img src="{{skin url='images/static-r-4-4.jpg'}}" alt="" /></div>
</div>"
```

But I do not see any change. I flush magento cache. No change.

Also I tried to add:

System/Permission/Blocks: CMS/Block

Still nothing happened.

I do not know what I should to check right now, why blocks are not visible...

Please help..

code from app\design\frontend\default\metrostore\template\catalog\product\home.phtml

```
    <?php elseif($config['home-page-option']==2):?>
<!--banner content static block content-->
<div class="main span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mlayer/mlayer')->setTemplate('mlayer/mlayer.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<div class="promoBox span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('bottom4_promotional_static_block')->toHtml() ?></div>
<!--end -->
<?php elseif($config['home-page-option']==3):?>
<!--banner content static block content-->
<div class="main span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mlayer/mlayer')->setTemplate('mlayer/mlayer.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<div class="promoBox span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('bottom3_promotional_static_block')->toHtml() ?></div>
<!--end -->
<?php elseif($config['home-page-option']==4):?>
<!--banner content static block content-->
<div class="main span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mlayer/mlayer')->setTemplate('mlayer/mlayer.phtml')->toHtml(); ?></div>
<div class="promoBox span12"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('bottom2_promotional_static_block')->toHtml() ?></div>
<!--end -->
<?php elseif($config['home-page-option']==5):?>
<!--banner content static block content-->
<div class="main span12 banner-col-2">
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mlayer/mlayer')->setTemplate('mlayer/mlayer.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('right3_promotional_static_block')->toHtml() ?>
</div>
<!--end -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: are you sure you are editing the right block? maybe you have an other one with the same name enabled for your store